# fill input into height and width of Bootstrap table cell

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table (using Bootstrap 3.0) with an input field in each cell

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="itemTable" border="1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th >Quantity</th>
                                <th>Unit</th>
                                <th>Material Name</th>
                                <th>PO Vatable</th>
                                <th>PO TAX</th>
                                <th>PO Total</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" name="Quan[]">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select id="BX_gender" name="Unit[]">
                                        <option>Kg</option>
                                        <option>Piece</option>
                                        <option>Meter</option>
                                        <option>Pound</option>
                                        <option>Gram</option>
                                        <option>Feet</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="Material[]"> </td>
                                <td><input type="number" step="0.01" class="small" name="POVATABLE[]"> </td>
                                <td><input type="number" step="0.01" class="small" name="POTAX[]"> </td>
                                <td><input type="number" step="0.01" class="small" name="POTOTAL[]" onkeyup="onRequestTotalModification(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)"> </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

I'm trying to set the input to have the width & height of the cell containing it, but nothing is working (even inline styling).
I organized the table using `thead` and `tbody` tags, but it didn't fix anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to have your input be the entire cell you need to remove bootstraps default padding on TD elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/2ay5yuq3/2/

```css
.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td, .table-bordered>tbody>tr>th, .table-bordered>tfoot>tr>td, .table-bordered>tfoot>tr>th, .table-bordered>thead>tr>td, .table-bordered>thead>tr>th{
  padding: 0;
}
```